# Need help using javascript with HTMLplayer

Tags: javascript

I want to create an html5 player that will play multiple audio files sequentially. I found the code below which works perfectly in playing the files when the page opens, but I want to be able to control the audio with a player and controls. Can anyone help me with this?

```js
var sounds = new Array(new Audio("https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"), new Audio("https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"), new Audio("https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"));
var i = -1;
playSnd();

function playSnd() {
  i++;
  if (i == sounds.length) return;
  sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', playSnd);
  sounds[i].play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by placing audio element with controls attribute **inside** the body element if I understood what you're trying to do.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Although it works, creating arrays with the **`new`** keyword is not recommended -- instead use the literal array:

`let arr =`<del>`new Array()`</del>
`let arr = []`

Using **`new Audio()`** creates an Object but not the HTMLMediaElement rendered in the DOM. In order to get the default controls we need to either write the markup in HTML or dynamically create an audio tag and append it to the DOM using JavaScript.

**HTML**
Note the `controls` attribute is needed to actually have the tag visible.

```
<audio src="http://example.com/path/to/file.mp3" controls></audio>
```

**JavaScript**
Here's the minimal script to dynamically add the same audio tag as above.

```
const audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
audioTag.controls = true;
audioTag.src = "http://example.com/path/to/file.mp3";
document.body.appendChild(audioTag);
```

The following demo has a playlist that can be controlled manually and loops automatically. Details commented in the demo.

```js
// Reference <audio>
const player = document.querySelector('audio');
// Reference <figcaption>
const skip = document.querySelector('.skip');
/*
Object
- base property is a string of host
- path property is an array of strings of each path
*/
const list = {
  base: 'http://soundbible.com/mp3/',
  path: ['chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3', 'Dial%20Up%20Modem-SoundBible.com-909377495.mp3', 'Fake%20Applause-SoundBible.com-1541144825.mp3']
};
// Number of paths
const size = list.path.length;
// Reference <output>
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
// Declare counter
let counter = 0;
// Declare loop flag.
let loop = false;
/*
Function pass list object
Ternary that resets count when min and max are exceeded
Change the value of <output> to count+1
Change <audio> src to new url interpolated from list .base and .path properties
load() and play() audio
*/
const playlist = list => {
  let count = counter >= size ? size - 1 : counter < 0 ? 0 : counter;
  item.value = count + 1;
  player.src = `${list.base}${list.path[count]}`;
  player.load();
  if (count >= size || count < 0) {
    player.pause();
  } else {
    player.play();
  }
  return false;
}

// Reister the ended event on <audio
player.onended = function(e) {
  counter++;
  playlist(list);
  if (!loop) {
    if (counter >= size || counter < 0) {
      counter = size - 1;
      e.target.pause();
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/* 
Register <figcaption> to click event
Delegate the click event to the e.target
e.target always points to the clicked element.
*/
skip.onclick = function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  if (target.matches('.prev')) {
    counter--;
  } else if (target.matches('.next')) {
    counter++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  playlist(list);
}
```

```css
button,
output {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loop.cont::before {
  content: '\1f501'
}

.loop.once::before {
  content: '\1f502'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <figure class='box'>
    <audio src='http://soundbible.com/mp3/chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3' controls></audio>
    <figcaption class='skip'>
      <button class='prev'>⏪</button>
      <button class='next'>⏩</button>
      <output class='item'>1</output>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <script>
    <!--Place JS here. The end tag of /body> should be the-->
    <!--only thing to follow the last < script > tag -->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do I stop it from looping? In other words,, how do I stop the playeronce the final file in the playlist has ended?

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine now. One final question - is there a way to have the audio files play consecutively in the player without the player reloading for each individual file? In other words, the multiple audio files would play like one longer file in the player

Comment: Only if you make one big file of all the mp3s  which is possible by using [Audacity freeware](https://www.audacityteam.org/) Don't forget to check the checkmark of this post to accept it.✅

Answer (score 0):

try this code with jquery1.7 (suppose you have jq in js folder), here complete page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>AudioPlayer-playlist</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<style>
.player{
width:340px;
padding:1px;
border:solid 2px black;
position:relative;
display:block;
background:steelblue;
margin:auto;
}
ul{
padding:0px ;
list-style-type: none;
background:yellow;
height: 280px;
overflow: auto;
margin-bottom:4px;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: silver;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightGray;
}
#playlist{
margin-top:0px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding:0px;
}
audio{
position:relative;
width:98%;
padding:0px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
border-radius:8px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
.active a{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
background:lightBlue;
}
li a{
color:black;
font-weight:bold;
padding:5px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
background:lightSteelBlue;
}
</style>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){

var audio, playlist, tracks, current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length;
    audio[0].volume = .60;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="player">
<ul id="playlist">
<li><a href="audio/01.mp3">song 01</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/02.mp3">song 02</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/03.mp3">song 03</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/04.mp3">song 04</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/05.mp3">song 05</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/06.mp3">song 06</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/07.mp3">song 07</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/08.mp3">song 08</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/09.mp3">song 09</a>
</li>
<li><a href="audio/10.mp3">song 10</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<audio id="audio" controls type="audio/mpeg">
Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio</audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you are misunderstanding my problem though. I would like the music files to play automatically and consecutively within the player, without requiring manual selection. For further clarification, when the page opens the visitor will click on the player and the playlist will then start. When item one ends item two in the playlist will commence automatically. If also do not need a visible playlist...

Comment: JBA You can put autoplay on your audio tag and display: none in your style. Autoplay it's not allowed by Chrome. I think You Can resolve with an iframe that loads your audio. Styling of course iframe display none . Believe me, autoplay it's not a good netiquette thing. The user must listen music when he wants and not when the webmaster wants

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used an iframe that load a page with the playlist in autoplay mode. Normally in Chrome this is not enough, autoplay
doesn'twork. I used embed tag (that allow autoplay) with an empty mp3 called sil.mp3, to trig the audio on the browser; in this
way the page loaded with iframe can autoplay. Here the code of the page with the iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Invisible Playlist Example page</title>
<style>
    embed {visibility: hidden;}
    iframe {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body
    <h3>This page is playing a Playlist even if you can't see 
      nothing:<br />
      there is an iframe that loads audio</h3>
        <embed src="audio/sil.mp3" autoplay></embed>
          <iframe src="mylist.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the code of the page loaded with the iframe (mylist.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Invisible Playlist Example</title>
<style>
    #playlist {display: none;}
    audio {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>This page is playing a Playlist even if you can't see 
 nothing:<br />
  audio = display:none; and has autoplay, not allowed in Chrome, 
   Opera</h2>
    <div id="playlist">
     <audio controls autoplay></audio>
    </div>
<script src="mylist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and at last the script (mylist.js) included in the page

```
(function () {

// Playlist array
var files = [
    "audio/song1.mp3",
    "audio/song2.mp3",
    "audio/song3.mp3"
];

// Current index of the files array
var current = 0;

// Get the audio element
var playlistPlayer = document.querySelector("#playlist audio");

// function that will be call at the end of the previous
function next() {
    // Check for last media in the playlist
    if (current === files.length - 1) {
        current = 0;
    } else {
        current++;
    }

    // Change the audio element source
    playlistPlayer.src = files[current];
}

// Check if the player is in the DOM
if (playlistPlayer === null) {
    throw "Playlist Player does not exists ...";
} else {
    // Start the player
    playlistPlayer.src = files[current];

    // Listen for the playback ended event, to play the next media
    playlistPlayer.addEventListener('ended', next, false)
}

})();
```

an example here http://giocaroli.xoom.it/pub/test/pag_loadin_playlist.html